# Osslsigncode overwriting a file while code signing

Tags: linux, docker, code-signing, codesign

I am performing a code signing using osslsigncode. I wanted to know if there was a way to overwrite the file being signed using the same name instead of creating a new one? I tried using the same name however I get an error saying file exists.

Current command:

`osslsigncode sign -pkcs12 "./my.pfx" -pass "${CERT_PASS}"  -in "/app/out/my.dll" -out "/app/out/mySigned.dll"`

What I would like(overwriting the file passed in):

`osslsigncode sign -pkcs12 "./my.pfx" -pass "${CERT_PASS}"  -in "/app/out/my.dll" -out "/app/out/my.dll"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not implemented in [osslsigncode](https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode) and the maintainer [is not going to support inplace signing](https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode/pull/68#issuecomment-777315169) yet. The fastest workaround is the rename/remove cycle.